# jquery multiple click issue

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
   {

        $("#build_table, a.coursename, .Start Date, .Book Title, .Book Author, .Book Isbn").click(function()
        {
            var whichButton = $(this).attr("class");
            console.log("Whichbotton = " + whichButton);
            var prog = $("#program option:selected").text();
            var sch = $("#school option:selected").text();
            var trm = $("#term option:selected").text();
            var ext = $("#extension option:selected").text();
            if(prog == "" || sch == "" || trm == "")
            {
                alert("Please enter a selection for each field");
            }
            else
            {
                $.get("build_table.php", {program: prog, school: sch, term: trm, extension: ext, button: whichButton},
                function(table)
                {   console.log("Entered table function");
                    $("#input_table").replaceWith("<div id='input_table'>" + table + "</div>");
                });
            }   
        });
   });
```

At the way beginning, I have a click function which I want to work for multiple butttons. This code will call a php file to build a table, and the resulting table headers have different class names (such as coursename). But it doesn't actually work for coursename, Start date, etc, only for build_table which was the button that built the table in the first place. Am I missing something? I know that the names are correct, I even tried to take the space out of one of them (a.coursename) and that still didn't work...

Comment: Really need to see the HTML to give a full answer, but with the information provided I will say that CSS classes cannot have spaces in them, otherwise how could a CSS parser tell the difference between a [combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#selector-syntax) and white space in a class name?

Comment: Agreed. You've asked `14` questions and accepted `3`. This is a community, and you have a part to play too.

Comment: Accepting/Upvoting the answer is the best way of appreciating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implement this and its work..
**HTML code:**

```
<input type="button" value="Build table" id="build_table"/>
<input type="button" value="Course name" class="CourseName"/>
<input type="button" value="Start date" class="StartDate"/>
<input type="button" value="Book title" class="BookTitle"/>
<input type="button" value="Book author" class="BookAuthor"/>
<input type="button" value="Book isbn" class="BookIsbn"/>
```

**jquery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#build_table, .CourseName, .StartDate, .BookTitle, .BookAuthor, .BookIsbn").click(function(){
            alert("Yehh!! Its wroked :)"); 
            //your further code

    });
});
```